# Variable not in scope: catch

Tags: haskell

I have this function to open a file with this code but it is returning

```
teste.hs: 228: 5: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      catch :: IO Handle -> (t0 -> IO Handle) -> IO Handle
```

My code:

```
opensArchive :: String -> IOMode -> IO Handle
opensFile file mode =
    catch (openFile mode file)
       (\ _ -> do {
     putStrLn ("Unable to open" ++ file);
     putStrLn "It will be opened with a default name: data.txt and cleared";
     pt_arq <- opensFile "data.txt" WriteMode;
     closeArchive pt_arq;
     opensFile "data.txt" ReadMode
      }
    )

closeArchive :: Handle -> IO ()
closeFile handle_arq = hClose handle_arq
```

[Haskell file open function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ihQ.png)

Comment: You might want to mention, in the very title of your question, that the problem is about Haskell failing to find function `catch`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the specifications for function `catch`.

Surf to [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org). Then enter “catch” into the search field at top left of the web page.

Then click on the top solution. That will land you on the [specification web page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catch) for function `catch`.

Going at the very top of that page, you will see it is about module `Control.Exception`. Did you import it yet ?

Testing under `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> :type catch

 <interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: catch
 λ> 
 λ> import Control.Exception
 λ> 
 λ> :type catch
 catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
 λ> 
 λ>
```

Voilà !